# Double blind review allowing arXiv submissions

Tags: conference, paper-submission, arxiv

I am submitting an article on a conference that follows a double-blind review system. However, the following is mentioned on its dual submission policy:

> Papers that have appeared on non-peered reviewed websites (like arXiv) or that have been presented at workshops (i.e., venues that do not have a publication proceedings) do not violate the policy.

So, if the above is true, I might as well have submitted a paper that has also appeared in arXiv, where the identities of the authors are visible. Wouldn't that effectively constitute a violation of the double-blind review policy?

Comment: Don't reviewers in double-blind systems have a code of ethics?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

> Wouldn't that effectively constitute a violation of the double-blind
>   review policy?

Clearly not, as they state that it doesn't violate the policy.

Does it break double-blinding? Yes. But the intent is clearly to allow those who submit preprints, are in fields where conference proceedings are a thing, etc. to still be able to submit. It's essentially a compromise position of "Double Blind where possible, but we're not going to kick you out if you've broken it through the standard course of research."

Comment: +1 There are plenty of other ways to break double-blinding too - perhaps your lab is the only one working on a particular application of a topic; perhaps the reviewers have seen you present an earlier stage of this work at a colloquium; perhaps the field site or type of samples you use will give you away. 100% double blind is often impossible, but we make do.

Comment: I'd also expect the reviewers to avoid deliberately breaking blinding by looking up who wrote the paper on arXiv, unless they have a reason that specifically involves authorship (e.g. suspected salami-slicing or plagiarism)...

Comment: @nengel Sometimes it's impossible to miss: for instance when the arxiv preprint appears on a search page for a related topic, or when google scholar notifies you automatically because they cite you or because  you 'follow' one of the authors.